# How to remove GrowlMail (on Mavericks)?

Tags: mail.app, macos, growl

I've installed Mavericks and started to us the Mail app from Apple again, but every time I start Mail I get the message:

> **Incompatible Plug-ins Disabled**
>
> Mail has disabled the following plug-ins:
>
> > Growlmail

[image]

I've tried disabling and removing it in the System Preferences under Growl but the message above keeps popping up when I start Mail.

How can I remove it?

Comment: @napcae Is this a mavericks only problem? since you added a the tag mavericks?

Comment: Now that you are saying that, I'd say it's rather a Mail 7 problem. But you wrote "(on Mavericks)" so I assumed it only occurs on the most recent OS. Is Mail 7 available for Mountain Lion? If not, then this is a Mavericks only problem.

Comment: Not sure that's why I didn't tag Mavericks and wrote "on mavericks between" `()` ;) / edit yes mail 7 is included in Mavericks.

Comment: So, I just checked this. `$system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)` and Mail `$ mdls -name kMDItemVersion /Applications/Mail.app/
kMDItemVersion = "6.5"`. Mail 7 is not included in [ML 10.8.5](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1676) Seems like a maverick only problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close Mail.app

Open a Terminal and enter `chflags nohidden ~/Library`.

Now you can navigate with your Finder to the following directories and delete the plugin `GrowlMail.mailbundle`:

- `~/Library/Mail/Bundles/GrowlMail.mailbundle`
- `/Library/Mail/Bundles/GrowlMail.mailbundle`

When starting Mail.app now, you shouldn't get any error messages related to GrowlMail.

Comment: I used the terminal also to rm -r the Growmail.mailbundle. But I couldn't find the second directory ( non user Libarary ) `/Library/Mail/Bundles/GrowlMail.mailbundle` But anyway It totally worked thanks!

Comment: If the bundle is installed in your home folder, it is only installed for the user which is logged in and has the plugin installed. The root library folder gives access to the plugin for every user on your system. You're welcome! :)

Comment: Don't forget to change ~/Library back to the hidden state!Also you can press Alt and go to the library from menu