# Unable to figure out how to disable/remove growl mail notifications

Tags: macos

I am trying to get rid of the GrowlMail notification. I have tried to follow instructions posted and can get into the Library to find the Mail folder but do not know how to find the /Library/Mail/Bundles/GrowlMail.mailbundle to remove the mail bundle. I am going in through the finder on OS X 10.9.3

I am a real novice so need clear steps to follow. The steps I have been trying are here: [How to remove GrowlMail (on Mavericks)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107239/how-to-remove-growlmail-on-mavericks/107240#107240)

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a link to the instructions you are following? also, Welcome to Ask Different!

Answer (score 1):

In Finder's "Go" menu there is a command "Go to Folder..." (or: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> when Finder is the active application)

If you paste in the `/Library/Mail/Bundles` it will take you to that folder.

I tried it on my computer and it didn't go (I just got an alert ding) because the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I got it out and am no longer plagued with that message.